# React updates page when starting axios post request with formdata

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

As soon as the request is called, the page updates and it is canceled seen in the chrome devtools console.
Request example:

```
await api.post("apiurl", dataForm, {
    headers: {
      authorization: `token`,
    },
  });
```

Google chrome console:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lN8Dg.png)

The problem happens yes and no, more often when sending a file larger than 2mb.

Comment: what is your ultimate goal please describe. Do you want that after api call finished then component will render?

Comment: The goal is to complete the request and return an "ok" message, but sometimes it sends normally but sometimes updates and cancels the request even by sending the same file.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: When running the project in prod after an npm run build and serving -s build the page no longer updates.